# Erro ao tentar recriar uma tabela com code first(Migration)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, ddd, migrations

Estou seguindo o tutorial do Eduardo Pires sobre DDD + Asp.Net MVC 5 + IoC e etc. Bem, na primeira tentativa para criar o banco e a tabela cliente, ficou jóia. Acontece, que o Eduardo fez algumas alterações e eu segui(estou aprendendo com ele) e fiz as mesmas. Bem, ele então deletou a tabela e a refez e eu fiz o mesmo. No momento que rodei(Update-Database -Verbose -Force) está me dando esse erro e com o Eduardo não(Copiei todo o trace que o VS2015 me gerou)

```
PM> Update-Database -Verbose -Force
Using StartUp project 'ProjetoModeloDDD.MVC'.
Using NuGet project 'ProjetoModeloDDD.Infra.Data'.
Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
Target database is: 'ProjetoModeloDDD' (DataSource: NOTEBOOK_INET\INETSOFTWARE, Provider: System.Data.SqlClient, Origin: Configuration).
No pending explicit migrations.
Applying automatic migration: 201703031708534_AutomaticMigration.
EXECUTE sp_rename @objname = N'dbo.Clientes', @newname = N'Cliente', @objtype = N'OBJECT'
IF object_id('[PK_dbo.Clientes]') IS NOT NULL BEGIN
    EXECUTE sp_rename @objname = N'[PK_dbo.Clientes]', @newname = N'PK_dbo.Cliente', @objtype = N'OBJECT'
END
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Ou o parâmetro @objname é ambíguo ou o @objtype (OBJECT) reivindicado está errado.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<NonQuery>b__0(DbCommand t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.NonQuery(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteSql(MigrationStatement migrationStatement, DbConnection connection, DbTransaction transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.ExecuteSql(MigrationStatement migrationStatement, DbConnection connection, DbTransaction transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsInternal(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbConnection connection, DbTransaction transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsWithinTransaction(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbTransaction transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsWithinNewTransaction(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsInternal(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsInternal(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbConnection connection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClass30.<ExecuteStatements>b__2e()
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbTransaction existingTransaction)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteOperations(String migrationId, VersionedModel targetModel, IEnumerable`1 operations, IEnumerable`1 systemOperations, Boolean downgrading, Boolean auto)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.AutoMigrate(String migrationId, VersionedModel sourceModel, VersionedModel targetModel, Boolean downgrading)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.AutoMigrate(String migrationId, VersionedModel sourceModel, VersionedModel targetModel, Boolean downgrading)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.UpdateInternal(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClassc.<Update>b__b()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.UpdateRunner.Run()
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner runner)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Update(String targetMigration, Boolean force)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.UpdateDatabaseCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
ClientConnectionId:edd714ba-f579-4999-bfe6-bdedb5b6240b
Error Number:15248,State:1,Class:11
Ou o parâmetro @objname é ambíguo ou o @objtype (OBJECT) reivindicado está errado.
```

Essas são as classes(Removi os using, para diminuir o espaço):

Context

```
namespace ProjetoModeloDDD.Infra.Data.Contexts
{
    public class ProjetoModeloContext : DbContext
    {
        public ProjetoModeloContext()
            : base("ProjetoModeloDDD")
        {

        }
        public DbSet<Cliente> Clientes { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
            modelBuilder.Properties()
                .Where(p => p.Name == p.ReflectedType.Name + "Id")
                .Configure(p => p.IsKey());

            modelBuilder.Properties<string>()
                .Configure(p => p.HasColumnType("varchar"));

            modelBuilder.Properties<string>()
                .Configure(p => p.HasMaxLength(100));

            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ClienteConfiguration());
        }
        public override int SaveChanges()
        {
            foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(entry => entry.Entity.GetType().GetProperty("DataCadastro") != null))
            {
                if (entry.State == EntityState.Added)
                {
                    entry.Property("DataCadastro").CurrentValue = DateTime.Now;
                }

                if (entry.State == EntityState.Modified)
                {
                    entry.Property("DataCadastro").IsModified = false;
                }
            }


            return base.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Entities

```
namespace ProjetoModeloDDD.Domain.Entities
{
    public class Cliente
    {
        public int ClienteId { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public string Sobrenome { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public DateTime DataCadasto { get; set; }
        public bool Ativo { get; set; }

        public bool ClienteEspecial(Cliente cliente)
        {
            return cliente.Ativo && DateTime.Now.Year - cliente.DataCadasto.Year >= 5;
        }
    }
}
```

Configuration

```
namespace ProjetoModeloDDD.Infra.Data.EntityConfig
{
    public class ClienteConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Cliente>
    {
        public ClienteConfiguration()
        {
            HasKey(c => c.ClienteId);

            Property(c => c.Nome)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(150);

            Property(c => c.Sobrenome)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(150);

            Property(c => c.Email)
                .IsRequired();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: coloca as classes relacionadas a esse código

Comment: @EduardoSampaio, fiz uma edição e coloquei lá as classes

Comment: existe essa tabela cliente  ja no seu banco?

Comment: Não entendi muito bem, você deletou qual tabela? você esta usando o migration  para fazer esse update?

Comment: Não, @EduardoSampaio, eu deletei essa tabela e já não existe mais. Então, o que eu não entendo na mensagem é que está dando anbiguidade no nome, mas eu já deletei, a menos que esse nome esteja em algum lugar e o Migrations está se perdendo aí. Mas onde?

Comment: @WilliamCézar, uso o Code First para gerar o BD e a tabela deletada é a única no projeto, até então, que é a tabela de Cliente. O Migration é que vai gerar o banco e as tabelas.

Comment: Voce adicionou um novo migration e depois deu Update-Database certo ?
O que apareceu quando você deu o comando Add-Migration "NomedoMigrartion"

Comment: @WilliamCézar, como assim um novo migration? Não entendi ou fiz algo sem saber o que estava fazendo. Pode me explicar? Agradeço.

Comment: Desculpe a demora, vou tentar te explicar de uma maneira rápida, O camando ´Add-Migration "QualquerNome"´ vai adicionar um novo migration com as suas alterações,  assim quando você der o Update-Database ele vai adicionar esse novo migration a sua tabela no Banco (Migration) e fazer as alterações, caso não houver nada de errado.
O que pode estar acontecendo e que na sua tabela migration ele ainda tem a referencia para a sua tabela deletada, por isso você precisa adicionar um novo.  Qualquer coisa eu respondo devidamente se for esse o problema.

Comment: quando você adiciona um novo migration ele vai adicionar o que mudou em relação ao ultimo e quando você da update ele vai fazer essas alterações diretamente no banco. Não sei se é esse se problema mas pode ser.

Comment: @WilliamCézar, cara tô perdidinho. Como assim novo Migration? Não entendi. Eu não tenho esse comando em meu código.

Comment: Esses comandos eu faço no Nuget, depois de ter feito as alterações no meu projeto, eu abro o console do Nuget  e digito Add-Migration "NomeDoMigration"  ai ele gera um nova classe com as alterações, e depois dou Update-Database e assim são feitas as atualizações.

Comment: @WilliamCézar, o que eu fiz foi apenas dar um `Update-Database -Verbose -Force`. Foi isso que eu fiz, pois acompanhei o Eduardo Pires e ele não fez mais nada, pelo menos na vídeo aula dele. Então, o que realmente eu devo fazer. Como assim nome do novo `migration`?

Comment: Esse compando Update-Database  você executa aonde? no Console Nuget certo ?

Comment: aqui tem algumas informações sobre o migration e como usar,(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591621(v=vs.113).aspx) qualquer coisa me passe o tutorial e eu vejo.

Comment: Sim, no console do NuGet

Comment: Então de o Comando Add-Migration , logo em seguida ele vai te pedir um nome você vai colocar o nome referente a mudaça , exemplo Add-Migration  removendoTabelaCliente, depois você da o comando Update-Database, pelo menos e dessa forma que faço, ai ele vai criar uma nova classe de migrations .

Answer (score -1):

Olá! tive o mesmo problema!!Consegui resolver adicionando na classe

> ProjetoModeloContext

o using:  `using System.Linq;`

O erro acho  que é gerado por conta da forma que o código foi escrito utilizando `Linq`